# simple java program connecting to database server using JDBC has execution time varying all over the place

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I've got a very simple java program (J.java, see below) on my application server that successfully connects to an Oracle 11.2 database on a database server (both servers are Linux CentOS) using JDBC thin driver from Oracle.

As you can see from the setURL command in the Java code below, I've configured the application and database servers to sit next to each other, and they're on the same network (cross-cable connected to each other), so there's no network traffic on these (development) boxes except my code.

The problem is the execution time varies a lot. If I run it 5 times, it (seemingly randomly) could take 0.01 seconds, or 10 seconds, or 50 seconds, or over a minute to execute. If it takes over a minute (roughly), the program doesn't complete, but the error shown below is returned instead.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

```
--------error returned when execution take more than about 1 minute-------
gn@host7 [~/fd]# java -cp ./ojdbc6_g.jar:. J
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:494)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:547)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:225)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:29)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:556)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:454)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:328)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:233)
at J.main(J.java: line 16)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:96)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:219)
at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:208)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:224)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:172)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:97)
at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:82)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:120)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:76)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1158)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1134)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:307)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:199)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:365)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:812)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:411)
... 8 more
```

The java code for: J.java is:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

class J {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn;
    // connect to database
    OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
    ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hrpwd@192.168.0.1:1973:mySID");
    conn = ds.getConnection();

    // create Oracle DatabaseMetaData object
    DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
    // show database version
    System.out.println("Database version is " + meta.getDriverVersion());

    if ( conn != null ) {
      try { conn.close(); } catch ( Exception ex ) {}
      conn = null;
    }
    } 
}
```

UPDATE 1:

This looks like the potential culpret:

http://www.usn-it.de/index.php/2009/02/20/oracle-11g-jdbc-driver-hangs-blocked-by-devrandom-entropy-pool-empty/

Anyone know how to actually implement the solution provided there (see item 3 at end -- where would I find this `-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom` to change it?)

Comment: Try a different method, this article says meta data methods are slow in JDBC. http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365579/Using-Database-MetaData-methods-appropriately But I am still leaning towards some network trouble, however improbable that sounds (in this situation).

Comment: Thanks skynorth. I simply chose to read metadata to keep the java code as simple as possible. If I replace the metadata query with anything else, such as reading a row from a table in the database, the same result happens.

Comment: Have you tried using the DriverManager in the java.sql package to see if using the OracleDataSource is what is slowing you down? I've never used the OracleDataSource before so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is as follows (from CentOS forums):

```
Try editing /etc/sysconfig/rngd to contain:

# Add extra options here
EXTRAOPTIONS="-r /dev/urandom"

Then "service rngd start". If that works, then "chkconfig rngd on" will start it at boot.
```

See also:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/entropy.txt

http://www.usn-it.de/index.php/2009/02/20/oracle-11g-jdbc-driver-hangs-blocked-by-devrandom-entropy-pool-empty/

https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=36209&start=0#forumpost156856

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3793101

Comment: Thank you SO much, I was pulling my hair out with this one. Just doing this on the java command line made a huge difference: `-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom`

Comment: -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom solved it for me too, and the first link is very interesting and explains the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your next step is probably to do your trials under a profiler so you can see where all the time is being spent.  I'm guessing it will be in one of those low-level socket operations, like the one that eventually throws "connection reset".  If that's the case your problem is either inside Oracle, or something related to the network (despite you being cross connected -- who knows).

Comment: Thanks dacc, could you give me any hints about potential profilers I could use? Are you talking about wireshark or something else (I'm fairly new to java and databases)?

Comment: The kind of profiler I'm referring to monitors your program while it runs, and adds up the time spent inside different methods.  For example, this is a good one: http://www.yourkit.com/ (30 day trial)

Comment: Hah! Amazing.  I guess the last suggestion in that article is worth trying: Run java with "-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom" (I assume you're on a Linux/UNIX machine?) If that works then consider whether your application will be OK using pseudo random numbers instead of entropy driven ones for securing your connection string and whatever else. =)

Answer (score 0):

On Debian `/etc/default/rng-tools` would be

```
HRNGDEVICE="/dev/urandom"
RNGDOPTIONS="-o /dev/random -t 1 -b"`
```

(Omnitted comments)

Answer (score 0):

We are launching from a shell script.  I included the `-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom` string as part of the java call.  Here's our entire command line:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -jar $1 $2 $PID
```